# Kann man einen Satz mit Infinitivkonstruktion mit dem Wort »mit« einleiten?

Tags: grammaticality, conjunction

> After this, the demand decreased a bit, with 34% of the respondents having participated in professional training in 2003 and 2007.

In einem Aufsatz wollte ich obigen englischen Satz, der eine Grafik beschreiben soll, auf Deutsch ausdrücken. Ich schrieb:

> Danach ließ die Nachfrage ein wenig nach, mit 34% der Befragten in 2003 und 2007 an beruflicher Weiterbildung teilgenommen zu haben.

Ich habe den Satz korrigiert zurückbekommen.
Kann man mit dem Wort *mit* Sätze auf solche Weise verbinden?

Comment: Falls eine Metabemerkung erlaubt ist: ich glaube, dass solche Fehler vermeidbar sind. Dein Deutsch ist offenbar gut genug, dass du den Satz umformulieren hättest können. Die Trial-and-Error-Direktübertragung von englischen Ausdrücken scheint mir zum Lernen ungeeignet, da hierbei zwar Konstruktionen, die es in beiden Sprachen gibt, durchs Sieb fallen, aber andererseits teils sogar gebräuchlichere Formen, die es im Englischen nicht gibt, unbeachtet bleiben. Persönlich würde ich daher immer bei bereits bekannten Formulierungen bleiben oder _aktiv_ nach alternativen Übersetzungen suchen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nein, *mit* kann man nicht analog zum englischen *with* einsetzen, um einen Satz mit einer Infinitivkonstruktion zu verbinden.

Das kann auch deswegen nicht funktionieren, weil in der englischen Konstruktion m. E. kein Gerundium, sondern ein Partizip Präsens vorliegt. Dieses entspricht nicht dem deutschen Infinitiv. *Having participated* müsste also mit *teilgenommen habend* übersetzt werden statt mit *teilgenommen zu haben,* was allerdings immer noch keinen gut lesbaren deutschen Satz ergäbe.

In der o.g. Form ist der Satz daher unverständlich.

Stattdessen kann man *wobei* verwenden, aber ohne Infinitiv:

> Danach ließ die Nachfrage ein wenig nach, wobei 34% der Befragten in 2003 und 2007 an einer beruflichen Weiterbildung teilgenommen haben.

Comment: Danke für das Beispiel, wie ein richtiger Satz  aussehen würde.

Comment: Aber Jahresangaben im Deutschen ohne "in". 2003 und 2007 haben sie teilgenommen, nicht in 2003 ...